# How can I show independent buttons in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, button, datagrid

I have a `DataGridView` with loaded elements from a database.
The problem is that I want to show a button in some rows (some elements need this button and some others don't) and I don't know how.
The only thing I have now is this code to show a 'delete' button but for every row.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btnDelete = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
dataGridView.Columns.Add(btnDelete);
btnDelete.Text = "Delete";
btnDelete.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by inserting DataGridViewButtonCells into the cells where you want the buttons.

For example:

```
var cell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
cell.Value = "Button text"
cell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
dataGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex] = cell;
```

The column doesn't need to be a button column, it can be a textbox column, for example.

Or you could go the other way, make a button column and:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    if (i % 2 == 1) // whatever the condition is
        dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[COLUMN_WITH_BUTTONS] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
```

You could also create a custom datagrid column and cell type (inherit from the ones which are the closest to what you need) which has a flag (that you add) that controls what is shown in the cell.

You don't need to do this immediately for the whole grid - you can change the grid at any time. For example, you can make a function that sets a cell to the appropriate type, then call it when something happens (in an event handler, etc).